# SDL2/ Qt C++ not reading joystick inputs but recognized

Tags: c++, qt, sdl

that's my main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "SDL.h"

#include <QDebug>

#undef main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    SDL_Window *window = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *windowSurface = nullptr;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_JOYSTICK_ALLOW_BACKGROUND_EVENTS,"1");
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);

    SDL_Joystick *joystick = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);

    qDebug()<<SDL_JoystickName(joystick);
    qDebug()<<(SDL_JoystickNumAxes(joystick));
    qDebug()<<(SDL_JoystickNumButtons(joystick));
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL CodingMadeEasy Series", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_Event ev;
    int x;
    bool isRunning = true;

    while(isRunning)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)
        {        
            if(ev.type == SDL_JOYBUTTONDOWN)
            {            
                qDebug()<<"Button Clicked";            
            }
        }    
        // Drawing the current image to the window    
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

it can recognize the PS4 Controller , as it prints out the qDebug lines.
i tried changing the ev.type == ( SOMETHING ELSE NOT JOYSTICK RELATED ) and it worked just fine, so apparently there is a problem with the JOYBUTTONDOWN.

any help?

Comment: What OS? Is it ok without qt? Are you sure you haven't disabled joystick events?

Comment: I am on windows 10.. Haven't tried without QT.

Comment: Care to tell me how to enable them? But i don't think i disabled them to begin with

Comment: you were right, it needed to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was fixed by Enabling joystick events

```
SDL_JoystickEventState(SDL_ENABLE);
```